# Why can't I get a simple Combobox to work in EXTjs 4 using a JSONStore?

Tags: json, extjs, combobox, extjs4

This is driving me insane.  I have a JS file that is:

```
  Ext.onReady(function(){
     Ext.QuickTips.init();

     var SitesStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        autoLoad: true,
        fields: [{
           name: 'id',
           mapping: 'id'
        }, {
           name: 'name',
           mapping: 'name'
        }],
        proxy: {
           type: 'ajax',
           url : '/sites/getsites.do'
        },
        storeId: 'SitesStore',
        root: 'sites',
        url: '/sites/getsites.do',
        xtype: 'jsonstore'
     });

     SitesStore.load(function(data){
        Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
           fieldLabel: 'Choose Site...',
           store: SitesStore,
           data: data[0].raw["sites"],
           queryMode: 'remote',
           displayField: 'name',
           valueField: 'id',
           renderTo: "timesheetSearch"
        });

        console.log(data[0].raw["sites"]);
     });

  }); //end onReady
```

My `/sites/getsites.do` returns `JSON` data in the following format:

```
{
    -sites: [
        -{
            id: "12345678"
            name: "Blah Warehouse"
        },
        -{
            id: "5999B91DF6C0"
            name: "WalMart Warehouse"
        },
        ...
}
```

I realize the `data[0].raw["sites"]` probably isn't the preferred way to access the data but I do confirm that the data is being populated and I'm getting back 136 `sites`.

The `combobox` **DOES** render.  However, the live search doesn't work and there are no entries.

I'm new to ExtJS.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

This code **WORKS**

```
var SitesStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['id','name'],
    data: [{'id':'aaaa', 'name':'Honeywell'}],
    storeId: 'SitesStore',
    root: 'sites'
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose Site...',
    store: SitesStore,
    queryMode: 'remote',
    displayField: 'name',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    valueField: 'id',
    renderTo: "timesheetSearch"
});
```

This does **NOT**

```
var SitesStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['id','name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/sites/getsites.do'
    },
    storeId: 'SitesStore',
    root: 'sites'
});

Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
    fieldLabel: 'Choose Site...',
    store: SitesStore,
    queryMode: 'remote',
    displayField: 'name',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    valueField: 'id',
    renderTo: "timesheetSearch"
});
```

When I run it without a `proxy` (and specify a `url`) I get an error saying I didn't specify a proxy.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

UGH!!!!!!

I got it.  Here is the correct `JSONStore`

```
var SitesStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['id','name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/sites/getsites.do',
        reader: {
            type:'json',
            root: 'sites'
        }
    },
    storeId: 'SitesStore',
    root: 'sites'
});
```

Thanks everyone.  Couldn't believe how hard this was.  Mainly because I couldn't find a good tutorial.  lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I was able to figure this out.  Here is the working code:

```
var SitesStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     autoLoad: true,
     fields: ['id','name'],
     proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '/sites/getsites.do',
        reader: {
           type:'json',
           root: 'sites'
        }
     },
     storeId: 'SitesStore',
     root: 'sites'
  });

  Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
     fieldLabel: 'Choose Site...',
     store: SitesStore,
     queryMode: 'remote',
     displayField: 'name',
     triggerAction: 'all',
     valueField: 'id',
     renderTo: "timesheetSearch"
  });
```

I never could get JSONStore to work so I created a standard `Store` and had to match the `reader` attribute with my `JSON` data.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit dirty and my first ExtJS4 lines (I am used to v2.x/3.x) but it should work. As I see you use a browser with console so you will be able to debug if there are some errors. Also you should take a look at the [API](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html)

```
 var SitesStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    autoLoad: true,
    fields: [{
       name: 'id',
       mapping: 'id'
    }, {
       name: 'name',
       mapping: 'name'
    }],
    proxy: {
       type: 'ajax',
       url : '/sites/getsites.do'
    },
    storeId: 'SitesStore',
    root: 'sites',
    url: '/sites/getsites.do'
    // ,xtype: 'jsonstore'
 });

  Ext.onReady(function(){
     Ext.QuickTips.init();


    Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
       fieldLabel: 'Choose Site...',
       store: SitesStore,
       // data: data[0].raw["sites"],
       queryMode: 'remote',
       displayField: 'name',
       valueField: 'id',
       renderTo: "timesheetSearch",
       listeners:{
            scope: this,
            'select': function(field, value){
                console.log(value);
            }
        }

    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't work.  I have looked at the API.  In fact, that API link you sent actually works.  But my jsonstore does not.

Comment: @cbmeeks ok, the use firebug to debug the store. It should load the time you click the combo. You can use the store events or comboBox event to debug this.

Comment: OK, I looked at Chrome and when I click the dropdown, I `DO` get a `200 OK` and the `JSON` is there.

Comment: Yes, I think so. You can do most with console.log() Post your store instance after it is loaded and have a look a the content. Maybe it is really empty. And I think you don't need a mapping in the storefields if the fieldname is the same

Comment: Thanks.  But I have confirmed the SitesStore does in fact load data

Comment: OK, I overseen the data property, try to remove it

Comment: Sorry? Didn't quite understand that one.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can you answer your own question with the working code please. I am interested myself in the solution.

Comment: I posted my answer but I can't officially answer it for 2 days per SO's policy.